# understanding Jvmstat graph

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am trying to use and understand the visualgc garbage collection monitoring tool for the first time. However, one of the multiple outputs on the graph, I couldn't make sense of. I tried this link which is an Oracle documentation on visualgc : - [visualgc - Visual Garbage Collection Monitoring Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/visualgc-136680.html)

Could not understand :

[image]
Graph showing compile time. I am confused with what it means by compile time. As per the documentation from above link it means that total time spent on compilation process but then why does it shows : 59 complies. Does JVM complie the code multiple times? Or 59 is just the kind of number of tasks JVM did to compile only once? I thought that code is complied only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "compilation" it is assumed that we're talking about Just-in-Time compilation of initially interpreted bytecode into native code. Yes, the same piece of Java bytecode may go through compilation several times. A familiar example is when a monomorphic call site's type assertion fails, forcing a recompile into a megamorphic call site. A method may have any number of call sites, so just this concern may cause any number of recompiles.

Also note that in modern architectures with dynamic bytecode generation, classes are often being generated, loaded, and unloaded as the program is running. This is another source of continuous JIT compilation.